# How can I click a href button using python 3.8 selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, partiallinktext

1. The problem:
   I'm trying to click this `href` here:

[image]

2. Fail attempts:
   I tried to use these to no avail

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_link_text('Join').click()
   driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('href').click()
   ```

Comment: In the image, there is a space before `Join`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that

Comment: @IsaiahLowe always copy the text even if you are spelling bee champ !

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath instead of link text.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(), "John"]').click()
```

Or add `space` in front of  `John`.

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text(' Join').click()
```

Comment: Where I put the xpath for ** driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(), "John"]').click() **

Comment: Replace this line `driver.find_element_by_link_text('Join').click()`

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **Join** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *partial_link_text*:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Join").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(., 'Join')]").click()
  ```

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Join"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., 'Join')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```